# Is it possible get a particular argument in printf format in perl in command line?

Tags: perl, arguments, printf

It's needed to build a string `foobar is not foo and not bar`.

In `printf` format `%$2s`, "2" means a particular argument position.

But it doesn't work in perl:

```
$ perl -e "printf('%$1s$2s is not %$1s and not %$2s', 'foo', 'bar');"
%2 is not %1 and not %2
```

My env:

```
$ perl --version

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 29 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, you mean like create a function? `perl -e "sub ppp () {printf ('%1$s%2$s is not %1$s and not %2$s', 'foo', 'bar');} ppp();"` like this?.. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your quoting is off.

```
perl -E 'say sprintf(q{%1$s%2$s is not %1$s and not %2$s}, "foo", "bar");'
foobar is not foo and not bar
```

You cannot use double quotes `""` for the `-e` because your shell gets confused. You need single quotes there. But if you use double quotes for the `printf` pattern with the `%1$s` syntax, Perl will try to interpolate the `$s`, which doesn't work. So use a non-quoting `q{}` or escape the single quotes `''` with `\'`. Or escape the `$`s.

If you turn on `use strict` and `use warnings` you'll see:

```
$ perl -E 'use strict; use warnings; say sprintf("%1$s%2$s is not %1$s and not %2$s", "foo", "bar");'
Global symbol "$s" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.
Global symbol "$s" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.
Global symbol "$s" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.
Global symbol "$s" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

That's with single quotes `''` for `-e` and double quotes `""` for the pattern.

```
$ perl -E "use strict; use warnings; say sprintf('%1$s%2$s is not %1$s and not %2$s', 'foo', 'bar');"
Invalid conversion in sprintf: "%1 " at -e line 1.
Invalid conversion in sprintf: "%2" at -e line 1.
%2 is not %1 and not %2
```

Now the shell tried to interpolate `$s` because of the double quotes `""`. So Perl never sees it. It sees the pattern as `"%1 %2 is not %1 and not %2"`, which it cannot understand. (Note that the `%` will not get interpolated in double quoted strings in Perl).

Comment: I got this point, thanks! What a bit unclear, if I use single quotes, why it leads an error: `perl -E 'use strict; use warnings; say sprintf(\'%1$s%2$s is not %1$s and not %2$s\', \'foo\', \'bar\');'`. error: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token ')'`

Comment: @Kirby that's a good question. If you remove the parenthesis `(` and `)` (you don't need them), it will just expect more input and not run your program. Off the top of my head I don't know what it doesn't like. But shell quoting and escaping is tricky. My suggestion is to use `q{}` for the pattern, and whatever you like for the args. I'd do `printf q{%1$d...}, qw(foo bar);` so I don't have to deal with quotes at all

Comment: Note that using `-E` isn't forward compatible, meaning that upgrading Perl could break the program. I recommend against using it except for one-off programs. You could use `-e` + `CORE::say` instead of `-E` + `say`.

Comment: @ikegami is right. I used it to get `say` so I'd have a new line. For the explanation it doesn't matter if you do `-e` or `-E`.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on *nix:

```
perl -e "printf('%s%s is not %1\$s and not %2\$s', 'foo', 'bar');"
```

See the [`sprintf` documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html), in particular the examples at the very end:

> Here are some more examples; be aware that when using an explicit index, the `$` may need escaping:
>
> ```
> printf "%2\$d %d\n",      12, 34;     # will print "34 12\n"
> printf "%2\$d %d %d\n",   12, 34;     # will print "34 12 34\n"
> printf "%3\$d %d %d\n",   12, 34, 56; # will print "56 12 34\n"
> printf "%2\$*3\$d %d\n",  12, 34,  3; # will print " 34 12\n"
> printf "%*1\$.*f\n",       4,  5, 10; # will print "5.0000\n"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at the program you pass to `perl`:

```
$ printf '%s' "printf('%$1s$2s is not %$1s and not %$2s', 'foo', 'bar');"
printf('%ss is not %s and not %s', 'foo', 'bar');
```

As you can see, there is no `$1` or `$2` in your program because you improperly built your shell command. Just like Perl interpolates in double-quotes, so do `sh` and related shells. You should be using single quotes!

```
perl -e'printf("%\$1s\$2s is not %\$1s and not %\$2s\n", "foo", "bar");'
```

(I would have suggested switching from `''` to `q{}` inside the Perl program so you wouldn't have to escape the dollar signs, but you need double-quotes for the `\n` you were missing anyway.)